# Creating a class inside a scope does not let global objects access methods

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to create a class in a scope but cannot call the method I made for it.  Why is this method not accessible?

**Code Snippet**

```
var ClientController;

(function($, cc){
    function ClientController(){
        this.GVNavUpdate = function(){
            console.log('this works');
        }
    }

    cc = new ClientController();

})(jQuery, ClientController);

ClientController.GVNavUpdate();
```

Comment: That makes no sense to me? You're passing the class as `cc` to the self invoking function, then inside it you're still using the class name, and overwriting the passed `cc` with a new `cc` ?

Comment: Why do you think your self-executing function should affect global scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var ClientController = (function($) {
    function ClientController() {

        this.GVNavUpdate = function() {
            console.log('this works');
        }

    }

    return new ClientController();
})(jQuery);

ClientController.GVNavUpdate();
```